# Shell script to act as watchdog

Tags: c, database, shell, fpga

I have an executable file which performs data acquisition from an interfaced FPGA and stores it in a specific format. Once in a while, randomly, the acquisition code stops citing receive error. However, re-running the executable works.

Hence one temporary arrangement is to run the executable in a shell script. The corresponding process needs to be monitored. If the acquisition stops (and the process ends), the script should re-run the executable.

Any hints on how to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your description, it sounds like you simply want an endless loop which calls the collector again and again.

```
while true; do
    collector
done >output
```

Redirecting the output outside of the loop is more efficient (you only open the file for writing once) as well as simpler (you don't have to figure out within the loop whether to overwrite or append).  If your collector doesn't produce data on standard output, then of course, this detail is moot.

Answer (score 0):

grep for the executable process in the shell script wrapper. If the PID is not found, then restart. You need to schedule the Shell wrapper as a cron job.

Comment: Instead of cron job, can I use while true; and add sleep in the loop?

Comment: You can, but if unix process gets killed somehow, it will be really messy. Crons keep periodic eye on the job and keep them running.

Comment: You can combine; a simple endless loop and a cron job which kicks the loop back up if it's killed. It might be needlessly complicated, though, and there's still no guarantee (if your system is under really heavy load, `crond` could be killed off as well!)